# How to prepare references for a research paper?

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, formatting

Say a research paper has more than 40 references. Does one have to write each and every citation by his hand as per the journal/conference's format or is there any automated way to do this?

Google Scholar provides the citation text of the required paper in some formats, also some websites provide the citations of the required paper. Does IEEE use any of the existing APA, MLA, etc. styles? Is using Bibtex a preferred way to prepare references? What is the efficient way to do this?

Comment: Honest question, honest answer: Did you spend any time trying to find and evaluate some answers to your question? Which would be research of your own?

Comment: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Creating_a_Bibliography

Comment: @Johannes_B :) yes sir, I tried finding the answers myself. That's where I got information on bibtex and google scholar citation. But not sure what's the efficient way to do it. And how do seasoned researchers do this?

Comment: @user5155835 Very area-dependent. In my subject area (chemistry), LaTeX is rare and Word is common, so it's mainly either by hand or using Endnote, and the latter is not always applicable. On the other hand, if LaTeX is supported then people tend toward BibTeX (though not everyone does, of course).